# Azure DSC - copying files from Storage Account with SAS - error "Relative path is not supported"

Tags: azure, powershell-dsc

When I try to copy website (even a single file) to VM with DSC, with the following configuration:

```
    File WebSiteContent {
        Ensure = "Present"              
        SourcePath = "https://MYBLOB.blob.core.windows.net/prod/index.html?sv=2016-05-31&ss=b&srt=s&sp=rl&se=2017-11-29T21:47:36Z&st=2017-07-26T13:47:36Z&spr=https&sig=SIG_HERE"
        DestinationPath = "C:\inetpub\backend\app_data" 
        Type = "Directory"
    }
```

I get an error:

`[ERROR] Relative path is not supported. The related file/directory is: https://MYBLOB.blob.core.windows.net/prod/index.html?sv=2016-05-31&ss=b&srt=s&sp=rl&se=2017-11-29T21:47:36Z&st=2017-07-26T13:47:36Z&spr=https&sig=SIG_HERE. \r\n`

Not sure what is the reason, since this is an absolute path to the file. Any suggestions to make it work are appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use xRemoteFile from the xPSDesiredConfiguration module

```
    File SetupDir {
        Type            = 'Directory'
        DestinationPath = 'c:\Setup'
        Ensure          = "Present"    
    }

    xRemoteFile SQLServerMangementPackage {  
        Uri             = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=824938"
        DestinationPath = "c:\Setup\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe"
        DependsOn       = "[File]SetupDir"
        MatchSource     = $false
    }
```